# How to open the website at the certain moment using shell?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I am looking for the solution how to open the website at the certain time. Considering the shell programming, it is possible to open website by the command:

```
$ open http://stackoverflow.com
```

How to do it at the certain moment if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `crontab` to make it.

> The crontab is a list of commands that you want to run on a regular
>   schedule, and also the name of the command used to manage that list.
>
> crontab stands for "cron table," because it uses the job scheduler
>   cron to execute tasks; cron itself is named after "chronos," the Greek
>   word for time.

Say You have a script `/bin/openURL.sh` to open a website,

```
30 21* * * /bin/OpenURL.sh
```

means executing it 21 : 30 every day.

More usage about `crontab`, see http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm

Answer (score 2):

For ***one-time* jobs** (scheduled tasks), **`at`** commands are **simple to schedule**, as demonstrated by John1024's since-deleted answer, but `at` has **drawbacks on OSX**:

- It must be *enabled* first; this is a one-time operation: `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist`.
- You must use `sudo` (have administrative privileges) to be able to schedule job with `at`.
- If a job produces any output, it will be *mailed* to the user using `mail`, as  stdout and stderr output (I don't know how to suppress this).
- Example: schedule opening http://stackoverflow.com *once*, at 19:00 (7 PM):

  - `sudo bash -c 'echo "open http://stackoverflow.com" | at 19:00'`

Using **`crontab`** for ***periodic* jobs** ***is* an option on OSX**; e.g., to schedule a job that opens http://stackoverflow.com every day at 19:00 (7 PM):

- Run `crontab -e` to open the current user's cronfile in your editor.
- Add the following line, save, and close the file:

  - `0 19 * * * open http://stackoverflow.com`
- If a job produces any output, it will be *mailed* to the user using `mail`, as combined stdout and stderr output (I don't know how to suppress this).

However, the **official recommendation on OSX** is to use **`launchd` for both one-time and periodic jobs**:

- `launchd` is very **flexible** and **centralizes all job scheduling**; as with `crontab`, there are system-wide and per-user jobs.
- the **downside** is that the **`.plist` files** required to define jobs are **cumbersome and non-trivial to create**.

Using our previous example:

**One-time job:** (opens http://stackoverflow.com *once*, at 19:00 (7 PM))

- Create file `~/test.plist` (for a one-off job, the location doesn't matter).
- Paste the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>TestJob</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>open</string>
    <string>http://stackoverflow.com</string>
  </array>
  <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
  <true/>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>19</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>00</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- `TestJob` uniquely identifies your job.
- Setting `LaunchOnlyOnce` to `true` ensures that the job is only run once.
- From Terminal, run `launchctl load ~/test.plist` to load the job.

**Periodic job:** (opens http://stackoverflow.com *every day* at 19:00 (7 PM))

- Create file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/testPeriodic.plist`

  - Note: The location matters: `~/Library/LaunchAgents` is where per-user job-definition `*.plist` files must reside in order to be loaded automatically at every logon.
- Paste the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>TestJobPeriodic</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>open</string>
    <string>http://stackoverflow.com</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>19</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>00</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- Again, `TestJobPeriodic` uniquely identifies your job.
- Jobs runs periodically *by default* (i.e., the *absence* of `LaunchOnlyOnce` makes the job periodic).
- From Terminal, run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/testPeriodic.plist` to load the job.

---

For background information, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23880156/45375.